Fail to install multiple packages from yml file with Conda
I have a simple issue (I think) that I could not solve so far. I'm trying to install a package: artic, from Bioconda. Here is the link: ARTIC
I installed Conda, then I created a virtual environment using a YML file to install other necessary dependencies, however,  the process failed because it could not find the packages, here is the YML file:
name: artic
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - artic-porechop =0.3.2pre
  - artic-tools =0.2.6
  - longshot =0.4.5
  - bcftools =1.17
  - biopython =1.81
  - bwa = 0.7.17
  - clint =0.5.1
  - htslib =1.17
  - medaka >=1.8.0
  - minimap2 =2.26
  - multiqc =1.15
  - muscle =3.8
  - nanopolish =0.14.0
  - pandas =2.0.3
  - pip
  - pysam =0.21.0
  - pytest
  - python =3.9.15
  - pyvcf =0.6.8
  - pyfaidx =0.6.0
  - requests =2.31.0
  - samtools =1.17
  - tqdm =4.66.1
  - keras-preprocessing =1.1.2

Now the error:
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - samtools=1.17*
  - pyvcf=0.6.8*
  - pysam=0.21.0*
  - nanopolish=0.14.0*
  - muscle=3.8*
  - minimap2=2.26*
  - medaka[version='>=1.8.0']
  - longshot=0.4.5*
  - htslib=1.17*
  - bwa=0.7.17*
  - bcftools=1.17*
  - artic-tools=0.2.6*
  - artic-porechop=0.3.2pre*

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I think that my main issue is that I forgot to install a major package (I do not know what), however, maybe someone could have another idea to fix this issue.

That's common. Conda has it's own 'store' with many channels, but Conda is focused mostly on scientific computing. They'll have all of the data and sciency stuff, but for other things you'll need to use pip. Just conda install pip, and then use pip for what Conda can't find.

my other alternatives is install one by one in a virtual environment, however, I do not think that is the best option

Can you share some screenshots? Did you activate your environment? If you just run python to open a repl, then run import sys  and print(sys.executable) does it give you your conda environment? conda install pip should work 100% of the time. Can you add the output of conda config --show to your original post, as well as some screenshots or copy-paste of the output around conda install pip?

Actually, I just looked at the docs for the artic package. They recommend setting the channel priority to false. This basically means that if conda can't find it where you tell it to look, they'll try to find it anywhere they can. You can find the code for that in the artic github readme, but installing pip is still a really  good idea.

Let me try again, if now works, I will update the post with the info that you ask me to share

I do not know what is going on:
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python```
for conda install pip:
```# All requested packages already installed.```

If I follow the conda config --set channel_priority false option, I still have the same issue

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After receiving help from Andrew in this post, and checking for some alternatives, I set the:
conda config --add subdirs osx-64

Most of the dependencies were installed in the conda environment following the instructions from the link that I provided, and if one dependency did not work, I installed it individually with conda
